# The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), &quot;boolean&quot; given

Tags: php, laravel-5, ip

The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given

```
Route::get('/user/ip', function(Request $request) {
    $ip =$request->ip();
    return Curl::to('https://ipapi.co/$ip/json/')->get();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Update `'` to `"` in following line and try.
`Curl::to("https://ipapi.co/$ip/json/")->get();`